# Why are Reference Counting GCs Stigmatised?

Tags: memory, garbage-collection, reference, reference-counting, mark-and-sweep

I once read somewhere about a common thought amongst idealistic yet 'lazy' programmers trying their hand at implementing programming languages. It was as follows:-

'I know, I'll do an easy-to-implement and quick-to-write reference counting GCer, and then re-implement it as a real GCer when I get the time.'

Naturally, this reimplementation never occurs.

However, I question why such a reimplementation is needed. Why are mark-and-sweep collectors of the incremental and concurrent variety seen as superior to the allegedly antiquated approach taken by languages like Perl 5 and Python? (Yes, I'm aware Python augments this approach with a mark-and-sweep collector.)

Circular references is the first topic to come up under such discussion. Yes, it can be a pain (see recursive coderefs in Perl, and fix to it involving multiple assignments and reference weakening.) Yes it's not as elegant when a coder has to constantly monitor for references of that ilk.

Is the alternative any better though? We can discuss fine-grained implementation details for eternity, but the fact is, most mark-and-sweep GC implementations have the following problems:-

- Non deterministic destruction of resources, leading to code that's hard to reason about and too verbose (see IDispose in .NET or the try/finally replacements in many other languages.)
- Additional complexity with different categories of garbage, for short-lived, long-lived, and everything in-between, with such complexity seemingly required for reasonable performance.
- Either another thread is required, or the execution of the program needs to be periodically halted to perform the collection.

Are the downfalls of mark-and-sweep justifiable to fix the issues of reference counting which are mitigatable with weak references?

Comment: "I once read somewhere" - where? Link please.

Comment: Can't remember. If it was making a precise technical point that would be a problem, but it's making a vague cultural point that I go on to elaborate, so it isn't particularly relevant IMO.

Comment: "Non deterministic destruction of resources". Reference counting is also non-deterministic in multithreaded programs as threads can race to decrement to zero.

Comment: "such complexity seemingly required for reasonable performance". Even the most naive tracing collector with no such complexity is *much* faster than naive reference counting. To make reference counting faster to have to add complexity too, and the state-of-the-art reference counting collectors are significantly slower than the state-of-the-art tracing collectors.

Comment: "the execution of the program needs to be periodically halted to perform the collection". That is incorrect. Collection can be fully incremental with no pauses.